# How to display a jpg file in Python?

Tags: python

```
def show():

    file = raw_input("What is the name of the image file? ")

    picture = Image(file)

    width, height = picture.size()

    pix = picture.getPixels()
```

I am trying to write a code to display this image but this code does not provide the image.
How to change my code in order to display this image?

Comment: remember to select an accepted answer for your question so that other might benefit from it as well.

Comment: Please search.  Please.  This a duplicate question.  All of these are relevant.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+display+image

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('File.jpg')
image.show()
```

Comment: this just launches an external viewer application

Comment: This answer requires that you install [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/installation.html#basic-installation) (or the original [PIL](https://bitbucket.org/effbot/pil-2009-raclette)) first. Note Pillow's syntax requires `from PIL import Image`.

Answer (score 22):

Don't forget to include

```
import Image
```

In order to show it use this :

```
Image.open('pathToFile').show()
```

Comment: have a 2nd place thumps up

Comment: `No Module named Image`