# Why is it that when I use imread () in python to read my image, it shows an image with a slightly different color than my original image?

Tags: python, opencv

I am wanting to use python OpenCV for image processing. This is my original photo:
[image]

I used the code below to load and show that image:

```
path = r"G:\3Y_individualProject\farm_colormap1.jpg"
colormap1 = cv2.imread(path)
plt.imshow(colormap1)
plt.show()
```

But it outputs an image of a slightly different color than the original image like this:[image]

Can someone tell me why there is such a difference? Thank you

Comment: Use Image / PIL instead for images: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333244/how-to-display-a-jpg-file-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opencv uses the BGR color scheme instead of the RGB color scheme. So your red is probably blue and vice versa. You can fix this with:

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Comment: img would be colormap1 in your example